# How to get the pointer to the initial Linux stack layout?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to access the original pointer to the [initial Linux stack layout](https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/) (argc, argv, envp, auxv) that gets passed to the `_start`-symbol of libc from the `main()`-function of a Rust program? This question is only for theoretical/playful/hacky experiments. I'm aware of `std::env::args()` and `std::env::vars()`.

The Rust abstractions make it hard "to get back to the ugly/low-level stuff". In fact, I like to go all the way back from: `main() --> ... --> std::rt::lang_start() --> _start()`

Comment: I am not sure, but I suspect that there would be a linker trick of some type that can make that happen.

Comment: You can use the `#![no_main]` attribute, and write your own C-like main.

Comment: Or use the [libc](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.112/libc/fn.getauxval.html) crate to call the functions that return those pointers.

Comment: @ libc: hm, this gives me the values of the aux vec, but not the bottom pointer to the stack layout itself.